# Enum as Dictionary keys

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

Suppose to have

```
enum SomeEnum { One, Two, Three };
```

SomeEnum is an enum so it is supposed to inherit from Enum so why if I write:

```
Dictionary<Enum, SomeClass> aDictionary = new Dictionary<SomeEnum, SomeClass>();
```

The compiler complains that it cannot implicitly convert SomeEnum to Enum?

Comment: Take a look at [Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx).

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria [*"Provides the base class for enumerations."*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx)

Comment: First row of documentation: Provides the base class for enumerations. A base class is not a parent class?

Comment: Yes, but enums are strange, don't thinks about enums like to the other classes.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria Why not? In this case they are equivalent. Here's the same error with regular classes: http://ideone.com/BbLGdH

Comment: @w0lf you're right sorry.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I believe that's because of [covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/).

In short:

`aDictionary` will be a `Dictionary<SomeEnum, SomeClass>`, but in the current context it is known as `Dictionary<Enum, SomeClass>`.

Had your declaration been allowed, the compiler should afterwards let you do:

```
aDictionary.Add(someValueFromAnotherEnumUnrelatedToSomeEnum, aValue);
```

which is obviously inconsistent with respect to the actual type of the dictionary.

That's why co-variance is not allowed by default and you have to explicitly enable it in cases where it makes sense.

The conclusion is that you have to specify the type exactly:

```
Dictionary<SomeEnum, SomeClass> aDictionary = 
    new Dictionary<SomeEnum, SomeClass>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Enum in its declaration is not a class that is equal to SomeEnum. It should be

```
Dictionary<SomeEnum, SomeClass> aDictionary = new Dictionary<SomeEnum, SomeClass>();
```