# Cannot implicitly cast enum to integer in C#

Tags: c#, enums, casting, type-conversion

I can define an enum with integer as value:

```
public enum FieldType 
{
    Bar = 0,
    Foo = 1
}
```

Why C# doesn't allow creating a dictionary with integer as a key and using an enum value when creating:

```
public Dictionary<int, Type> _fieldMapping = new Dictionary<int, Type>
{
    {FieldType.Bar, null},  # Error in VS
    {FieldType.Foo, null},  # Error in VS
}
```

I know i can do a cast, but i would like to know why enum cannot be converted to int implicitly when it actually is int under the hood.

Comment: It is because of `Covariance`, Check out the Answer of w0lf in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716734/enum-as-dictionary-keys

Comment: `Dictionary<int` doesn't make sense, if you expect `FieldType` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you could do that, you'd lose half the point of using enums at all - the point is to keep them as separate types to avoid you making mistakes involving using types incorrectly.

It seems to me like your dictionary should *actually* have `FieldType` as the key - at which point you'd have a safer approach. With your current expectation, you're expecting to be able to use *any* (`int`-based) enum type as the key, including things like `FileShare` which are clearly inappropriate.

So basically, you should ask yourself whether fundamentally you've got a map from field type to type, or whether you've really got a numeric map. To put it another way, without looking at `FieldType` at all, does an entry in the map from the number 1 to some `Type` mean anything? What does the 1 value represent there?