# Enum→int universal cast in packed collections

Tags: c#, enums, casting, packing

In my situation, I need to store dictionary objects of `Dictionary<SomeEnum, string>` type in `object` variable. `SomeEnum` is always different type with underlying type is an `int`. On another side I need to convert object to `IDictionary<int, string>`, but after two days of thinking nothing worked. 
Let me show a some kind of example:

```
enum Things: int {A, B, C}
//few lines are skipped
IDictionary<Things, string> dict = new Dictionary<Things, string>(){
{Things.A, "A"},
{Things.B, "B"},
{Things.C, "C"}};
object a = dict;
var b = a as IDictionary<System.Enum, string>; //not working
var c = a as IDictionary<int, string>; //not working too
var d = a as IDictionary<object, string>; //at least we tried
```

What I'm doing wrong? Even `IDictionary<KeyValuePair<System.Enum, string>>` not works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enum as Dictionary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716734/enum-as-dictionary-keys)

Answer (score 1):

IDictionary only has invariant type parameters. You really have to create a new dictionary by copying everything over. Or you create a wrapper that can look up the key converted to your enum.