# Using Dictionary<Enum, string> doesn't work

Tags: c#, dictionary, enums

I'm trying to create a Dictionary which has a generic Enum type as the key, this is how my class looks:

```
public class Error : IError
{
    public StatusEnum Status { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<Enum, string> Errors { get; set; }

    public Error(StatusEnum status, Dictionary<Enum, string> errors)
    {
        Status = status;
        Errors = errors;
    }
}
```

And I have an enum class like so:

```
public enum IdentityErrorEnum
{
    PasswordRequiresDigit,
    PasswordRequiresLower,
    PasswordRequiresNonAlphanumeric,
    PasswordRequiresUpper,
    PasswordTooShort
}
```

An `EnumHelper` which converts a string to an enum:

```
 public static class EnumHelper
 {
     public static T FromString<T>(string value)
     {
        return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value);
     }
 }
```

Finally, I'm trying to convert the collection of errors into a `Dictionary<Enum, string>` like this where result is an `IdentityResult`:

```
var result = await base.CreateAsync(_userMapper.ToEntity(user), password);
Dictionary<Enum, string> dictionary = result.Errors.ToDictionary(e => EnumHelper.FromString<IdentityErrorEnum>(e.Code), e => e.Description);
```

But this gives a build error which says:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<IdentityErrorEnum, string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Enum, string>'
```

Comment: Your example won't compile and it isn't obvious what result is. As far as I can tell, it does NOT match your error class since it contains `Code` and `Description`. You question should easily reproduce the problem without a lot of inference on the part of the answerer.

Comment: This is a covariance problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18716734/1462295

Comment: @DavidL Apologies, i edited the question

Comment: You are missing a cast :  [System.Enum]  : Dictionary<Enum, string> dictionary = Enum.GetValues(typeof(IdentityErrorEnum)).Cast<IdentityErrorEnum>().ToDictionary(x => (System.Enum)x, y => y.ToString());

Answer (score 1):

Your assignment is to a variable of type `Dictionary<Enum, string> dictionary`, but what you are returning from your `.ToDictionary` call is `Dictionary<IdentityErrorEnum, string>`. You just need to update your variable declaration or use var.

```
Dictionary<IdentityErrorEnum, string> dictionary = result.Errors.ToDictionary(
    e => EnumHelper.FromString<IdentityErrorEnum>(e.Code), 
    e => e.Description);
```

If in turn you want your dictionary to contain multiple enums (even though your .ToDictionary() call doesn't express this currently), you would need to cast back to enum.

```
Dictionary<Enum, string> dictionary = result.Errors.ToDictionary(
    e => (Enum)EnumHelper.FromString<IdentityErrorEnum>(e.Code), 
    e => e.Description);
```

Comment: Is there no way to achieve it though the Dictionary? It'll mean I'll have to add the enum everytime I instantiate an Error class

Comment: Eventually I want to assign this dictionary to the Errors property inside the Error class, the Errors dictionary must keep `Enum` as it's key as this could be any enum if that makes sense, how would I achieve this to be a generic enum?

Comment: @KTOV I misread your original question due to the missing details. There's no need for additional generics with Error.  You just need to update your variable declaration.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is.. I need to keep Dictionary<Enum, string> inside the `Error` class as generic as possible because this will have multiple enums not just `IdentityErrorEnum`

Comment: Note that [`Enum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum) is a class. It is more efficient to convert the enum values to `int` and to use a `Dictionary<int, string>`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes the OP is calling Enum.Parse per value. There’s a lot more efficiencies to be gained before using int, although it’s a great point. It is worth noting that if the OP is relying on the string representation and not the integer representation of the key, that will change the behavior as well.

Comment: There is also a `Parse<TEnum>(String)` and a `TryParse<TEnum>` directly returning a value type. Instead of `(T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value)` use `Enum.Parse<T>(value)`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes casting to int will lose type information, but the dictionary is supposed to contain multiple types, so won't be able to convert int back to correct enum.